# Is it possible to get the urls of images that are attached in ActiveStorage and see them on console in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if it is possible to get the urls that are attached to an object and see them on console in Ruby?

This time, I am going to create a method that can return the urls of attached images the attached images.

just to make sure how to do it, I am trying to do something like the one below on console.

on console,

```
item = Item.first
item.url_for([:images])
```

but the error says undefined method `url_for' for #<Items

So I am wondering if anyone can help me solve this.

after solving this problem I want to create a method something like this.
each of item has its multiple images in ActiveStorage

```
def get_images_url
   images_url = Items.map do |item|
   item.getting_url_images
   end
   images_url
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to call the route helpers outside of controllers or views:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images

  # @example
  #   item = Item.find(1).image_urls
  # @return [Array] - an array of urls
  def image_urls
    item.images.map do |attachment|
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(attachment)
    end
  end

  # @example
  #   urls = Item.all.image_urls
  # @return [Array] - an array of arrays
  def self.image_urls
    self.map(&:image_urls)
  end
end
```

See [Active Storage Overview: linking to files](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(attachment)" returns an error that says "Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true" but I can't set :only_path like, " url_for(attachment, :only_path to true" because it can only receive one argument. 
So, just to make sure, I tried this "Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(attachment, only_path: true)" it seemed worked fine, but I just got paths of an array not urls of array, so I still have things to do.

Comment: after reading the reference you gave me, I could solve this by setting the default_url_options. thank you so much.